# ValidationSummary binding issue. Silverlight. DataForm

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I've got DataForm "A" with its' own ValidationSummary and viewmodel. And there are other DataForms in grid that is placed in the dataform "A". 
So when some error raises in one of the grids' viewmodels the error shown in the inner dataforms' validationsummary and in "A" validationsummary. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty clear :) 
Just handle **BindingValidationError** event in both DataForms.